# Sending an email using the gmail api

Tags: python, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api, mime

I am writing a simple script to send an email using the google api:
My code looks like:

```
import httplib2
import os
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client, tools
import base64
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from apiclient import errors, discovery
import mimetypes
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Send Email'

def get_credentials():
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'gmail-python-email-send.json')
    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
        print ('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def SendMessage(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain, attachmentFile=None):
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
    if attachmentFile:
        message1 = createMessageWithAttachment(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain, attachmentFile)
    else: 
        message1 = CreateMessageHtml(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain)
    result = SendMessageInternal(service, "me", message1)
    return result

def SendMessageInternal(service, user_id, message):
    try:
        message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
        print ('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
        return message
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)
        return "Error"
    return "OK"

def CreateMessageHtml(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = to
    msg.attach(MIMEText(msgPlain, 'plain'))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(msgHtml, 'html'))
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(msg.as_string())}



def main():
    to = "user@gmail.com"
    sender = "user@gmail.com"
    subject = "testing"
    msgHtml = "Hi<br/>Html Email"
    msgPlain = "Hi\nPlain Email"
    SendMessage(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, when I run this script, I get the error that: 
[image: Screenshot]

I went to go ensure the files existed, and navigated to the path. The directory contained these files:
[image: screenshot]

so clearly the clientsecrets.py file does exist. I am unsure of how to resolve this error, as the file is clearly there and the terminal does map the file correctly. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In your error message of above image, it can see ``No such file or directory: 'client_secret.json'``. Do you have it? If you don't have it, you can see how to retrieve ``client_secret.json`` at Step 1: Turn on the Gmail API of [https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python).

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that!!

Answer (score 1):

In your error message We can see No such file or directory: 'client_secret.json'. Do you have it then store it in your current directory If you don't have it, you can see how to retrieve client_secret.json using [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)

**Don't forget to turn on your gmail API**